# ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit when using PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I am trying to get my old project [clipmanager](https://github.com/scottwernervt/clipmanager) building and I am encountering the following error:

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/clipmanager27/bin/python /home/user/development/clipmanager/clipmanager/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/development/clipmanager/clipmanager/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from mainwindow import MainWindow
  File "/home/user/development/clipmanager/clipmanager/mainwindow.py", line 12, in <module>
    import dialogs
  File "/home/user/development/clipmanager/clipmanager/dialogs.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PySide import QtWebKit
ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I installed `Pyside` with `pip install pyside`. I do not even see `QtWebKit.so` in the site packages folder `/home/user/.virtualenvs/clipmanager27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide`:

[image: folder view of pyside package]

Did it get removed due to licensing?

Comment: Nothing to do with licencing. I doubt that pip would attempt to build modules like webkit if you don't have all the necessary dev packages (i.e. header files) installed.

Comment: You are correct. I had to install [qtwebkit](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qtwebkit/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Arch Linux, install [qt4](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt4/) and also [qtwebkit](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qtwebkit/) before installing PySide.